# How to save a file as .map?

Tags: sas, geocoding

I am trying to work my way through this tutorial:

http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Geocoding_using_SAS_and_Google_Maps

I created a new directory to store all the files, but am having trouble this this part:

```
The code below needs to be saved as --Googlexmlmap.map'
```

Whenever I try to save it as Googlexmlmap.map, my computer saves it as Googlexmlmap.map.txt

Help?

Thanks

Comment: How are you saving the file? In Notepad make sure the set SAVE AS type to All Files, not .txt

Comment: In Notepad, but this helped me figure it out. I had to drop the .txt extension using the tutorial here: http://www.howtohaven.com/system/show-file-extensions-in-windows-explorer.shtml